# Using Phoenix with Hbase standalone throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have downloaded the tar.gz package for Hbase(1.1) and Phoenix(4.4 for hbase 1.1)

Setting up hbase in standalone mode works, I can get into the hbase shell.

Next I placed all .jar files from the the phoenix dir into Hbase's lib folder.

However, every time I try to start the sql shell I get the following error.
I've been at this all day and am staring myself blind here.

The installation instructions on the Phoenix website are pretty short, they basically say, copy the jars, run the .py script.

> **UPDATE:** Should anyone encounter the same Problems, I didn't manage to fix this (yet) but trying on a fresh machine worked for me. So it's probably some conflicting libraries somewhere.

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-224 ~]$ phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-1.1-bin/bin/sqlline.py localhost
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:localhost none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:localhost
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
15/06/03 09:09:55 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/06/03 09:09:57 WARN impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-phoenix.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
15/06/03 09:10:01 WARN ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel: Call failed on IOException
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:56)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.createTable(MetaDataProtos.java:10695)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1261)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$16.call(HTable.java:1727)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:32675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1615)
    ... 13 more
15/06/03 09:10:01 WARN client.HTable: Error calling coprocessor service org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService for row \x00SYSTEM\x00CATALOG
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1695)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1024)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1004)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1249)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:112)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1902)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:744)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:186)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:303)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:295)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:293)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1236)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1891)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1860)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1860)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:131)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:157)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:203)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1064)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:996)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:804)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:588)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:656)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:56)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.createTable(MetaDataProtos.java:10695)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1261)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$16.call(HTable.java:1727)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:32675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1615)
    ... 13 more
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more (state=08000,code=101)
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more

    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1041)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1004)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1249)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:112)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1902)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:744)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:186)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:303)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:295)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:293)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1236)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1891)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1860)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1860)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:131)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:157)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:203)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1064)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:996)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:804)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:588)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:656)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
    ... 10 more

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:56)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.createTable(MetaDataProtos.java:10695)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1261)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$6.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$16.call(HTable.java:1727)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: SYSTEM.CATALOG: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1149)org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10515)
```

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1674)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31447)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment.getRegion()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/Region;
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.createTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1054)
        ... 10 more
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:32675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1615)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: I don't think I have. I moved down to Hbase 1.0.0 (Apache, not cloudera or anything) and the matching Phoenix version. That worked instantly by copying the correct jar.
sqlline.py localhost:2181:/hbase connected as it should have

Answer (score 0):

Do not copy all the phoenix jars to `hbase`. Use this link for installation:https://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html

Now in terminal go to the phoenix directory (which you have extracted from tar.gz) and then run below command:

```
user@user:~/Downloads/phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-1.1-bin/bin$ ./sqlline.py localhost
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I ended up placing all the jars in the hbase lib folder out of sheer frustration, simply adding the server/client/.../ jar alone doesn't work and yields the same results for me.